# Javascript Multidimensional array form html list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I'm seriously getting crazy with a huge problem ....
I've got an html list like :

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Fiat</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Punto</li>
      <li>Croma</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Ford</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Focus</li>
      <li>Fiesta</li>
      <li>bla bla...</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

(i can change the html if necessary, but that would be the general idea of the list)
now... i need to put the data into 2 textboxes using javascript hint, so who would type a few letter would have the list ...

the main problem is converting that list in a javascript array so i can update the second textbox according to the brand previously selected ... 
Is a good idea using a multidimensional array ? 
Anyone able to give me the code to transform that nested list into a multidimensional array ?
Better ways to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what if you created the multidimensional array or object and then create the list and textbox from the array instead of going from list to array to textbox

Comment: No, I wouldn't use a multidimensional array. It would make the code quite hard to read, because the array dimensions are not self-explanatory and are their meaning is quite distinct from each other.

Comment: To get the list values into an array, you can simply do:

   `var listValues = $("ul li").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();`

Comment: @depperm i create that list from behind code ( i access that from an external database) dont really wanna parse data from behind code to javascript ... it make me feel like unsecure of what can happen

Comment: you can only use numbers as keys in javascript arrays.  to get something like an associative array you will have to use objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend this structure:

```
[
    { brand: "Fiat", models: ["Punto", "Croma"] },
    { brand: "Ford", models: ["Focus", "Fiesta"] }
]
```

To build it from the html you could do this:

```
var arr = [];
$("#main>li").each(function() {
    var elem = {
        brand: $(this).find(">span:first").text(),
        models: []
    };
    $(this).find(">ul>li").each(function() {
        elem.models.push($(this).text());
    });
    arr.push(elem);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paska/9hbjbp3L/

You need to add the id to the first `ul` only.

Another option that could be good (you should pick one based on how you use it):

```
{
    Fiat: ["Punto", "Croma"],
    Ford: ["Focus", "Fiesta"]
}
```

The code:

```
var objs = {};
$("#main>li").each(function() {
    var brand = $(this).find(">span:first").text();
    objs[brand] = [];
    $(this).find(">ul>li").each(function() {
        objs[brand].push($(this).text());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paska/Lj5Luqek/

Comment: That was just what i was actually looking for :)
Just perfect :)